# Orchard Azure Website Error

Tags: azure, orchardcms, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have a orchard website hosted on azure is connected to a sql azure database,I keep getting No row with the given identifier exists[Orchard.Roles.Models.PermissionRecord#33] here is the stack trace.

```
[ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists[Orchard.Roles.Models.PermissionRecord#33]]
NHibernate.Impl.DefaultEntityNotFoundDelegate.HandleEntityNotFound(String entityName, Object id) +56
NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.CheckTargetState() +48
NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.Initialize() +87
NHibernate.Proxy.DefaultLazyInitializer.Intercept(InvocationInfo info) +85
PermissionRecordProxy.get_Name() +192
Orchard.Roles.Services.RoleService.GetPermissionsForRole(Int32 id) +128
Orchard.Roles.Services.RoleService.GetPermissionsForRoleByNameInner(String name) +37
Orchard.Roles.Services.<>c__DisplayClasse.<GetPermissionsForRoleByName>b__d(AcquireContext`1 ctx) +26
Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.CreateEntry(TKey k, Func`2 acquire) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\Cache.cs:57
Orchard.Caching.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Get>b__0(TKey k) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\Cache.cs:19
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func`2 addValueFactory, Func`3 updateValueFactory) +125
Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.Get(TKey key, Func`2 acquire) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\Cache.cs:17
Orchard.Caching.DefaultCacheManager.Get(TKey key, Func`2 acquire) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\DefaultCacheManager.cs:33
Orchard.Roles.Services.RoleService.GetPermissionsForRoleByName(String name) +100
Orchard.Roles.Services.RolesBasedAuthorizationService.TryCheckAccess(Permission permission, IUser user, IContent content) +595
Orchard.Security.Authorizer.Authorize(Permission permission, IContent content, LocalizedString message) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Security\Authorizer.cs:72
Orchard.Security.Authorizer.Authorize(Permission permission) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Security\Authorizer.cs:60
Orchard.Security.SecurityFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Security\SecurityFilter.cs:24
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +97
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +311
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__19() +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:162
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I've looked in the database at PermissionRecord table and there is no ID #33 in the database at all. When I download the orchard website to webmatrix to do local development on it, the website gives me no errors at all and works fine it's also correctly connected to the sql azure database. So I am a bit confused as to why this doesn't work on azure because it works locally and it should be using the same files as on the azure website since I downloaded the files directly from the azure website. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite well overdue, but I ran into a similar situation this morning on orchard 1.6. Not sure how it occurred though! I hope this helps to anyone else that stumbles onto the same problem.

(I presume I had changed a modules permissions after it was enabled ages ago and hadnt noticed any problems until assigning a broken role to a user)

I used this bit of sql to find the offending record:

```
SELECT        TOP (1000) MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_RolesPermissionsRecord.Id, MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_RolesPermissionsRecord.Role_id, 
                     MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_RolesPermissionsRecord.Permission_id, MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_RolesPermissionsRecord.RoleRecord_Id, 
                     MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_RoleRecord.Name AS RoleName, MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_PermissionRecord.Name AS PermissionName, 
                     MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_PermissionRecord.FeatureName AS PermissionFeatureName, 
                     MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_PermissionRecord.Description AS PermissionDescription
FROM            MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_RolesPermissionsRecord LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_PermissionRecord ON 
                         MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_RolesPermissionsRecord.Permission_id = MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_PermissionRecord.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_RoleRecord ON MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_RolesPermissionsRecord.Role_id = MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_RoleRecord.Id
WHERE        (MyPrefix_Orchard_Roles_RolesPermissionsRecord.Role_id = 1) -- broken administrator role
```

Found that there were two records that were missing Permission records. One which had the RoleRecord_Id set to NULL and the other set to 1 - the admin. So when the permissions were loading with admin it would fail on looking up the Permission record. This helped the logging in part.

A couple of the role sections in admin still seemed broken: "Admin/Roles" so i ran the sql script above to find more of the offending rows from different roles.

I presume the random rows wont cause any problems and everything else seems to work as expected again.

Thanks, Matt